# I have a D3d10.dll file and in order to use it the DLL file has to be an application extension DLL file

Tags: dll, direct3d10

***I have a D3d10.dll file and in order to use it the DLL file has to be an application extension DLL file***

Blue marking is my view and red marking is my friends view, I need to get my DLL files like his can anyone help? [RED MARKING IS A FRIENDS POV] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDi1Y.png)

[BLUE MARKING IS MY POV] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/76so9.png)

Can anyone help?

I searched around YouTube, reddit and other sources of the internet and no one, seemed to solve my problem.

Comment: ``D3D10.DLL`` is a Windows OS system file, so you should not create your own DLL with that name. If your DLL needs it, then what's the error you are getting exactly?